# How to make a placeholder surrounded by rectangular box in html/css and angular material?

Tags: html, css, angular-material, placeholder, contentplaceholder

I have a design below (`Start Date`, `End Date` and `Please enter unavailability Reason` are placeholders `surrounded by rectangular box`) which I am trying to replicate in HTML/CSS and angular material.

In the following design, I am unable to make a `rectangular box over the placeholders` as shown in the 2nd image.

[image]

At this moment, I am able to get the below design with the HTML and CSS codes following it (`with no rectangular box over the placeholders`).

**Problem Statement:** I am wondering what changes do I need to make in my below HTML and CSS codes in order to `put a rectangle box` over the placeholders (In HTML `PORTAL.StartDate`  is `Start Date`, `PORTAL.EndDate` is `End Date` and `Portal.UnavailabilityReason` is `Please enter Unavailability Reason` are placeholders as shown in the 1st image. )

[image]

**HTML**:

```
<div class="component-title">
  {{'PORTAL.UNAVAILABILITY' | translate}}
</div>
<mat-toolbar>
  <div class="container"
       fxLayout="row"
       fxLayout.xs="column"
       fxLayoutGap.xs="0">
    <div>
      <h1>{{componentTitle}}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-toolbar>
<form class="unavailability-form" [formGroup]="unavailabilityForm" *ngIf="loaded">
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
      <div class="container" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap.xs="0" fxLayoutGap="10px">
        <div class="start-date" fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="1">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="{{'PORTAL.STARTDATE' | translate}}" type="text" formControlName="startDate" [readonly]="!componentPermission.writePermission">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="end-date" fxFlex="50%" fxFlexOrder="2">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="{{'PORTAL.ENDDATE' | translate}}" type="text" [min]="unavailabilityForm.controls.startDate.value" formControlName="endDate" [readonly]="!componentPermission.writePermission">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap.xs="0" fxLayoutGap="10px">
        <div class="unavailability-reason">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="{{'PORTAL.UNAVAILABILITYREASON' | translate}}" type="text" formControlName="unavailabilityReason" [(ngModel)]="unavailability.unavailabilityReason" [readonly]="!componentPermission.writePermission">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
      <div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap.xs="0">
        <div class="confirm-button" fxFlex="100%">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!unavailabilityForm.valid || !componentPermission.writePermission" (click)="onSave()">{{'PORTAL.CONFIRM' | translate}}</button>
          <!--<button mat-raised-button [matDialogClose]="canceled" color="primary">{{'PORTAL.CANCEL' | translate}}</button>-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container
{
  padding-top: 2%;
}


.start-date
{
  text-align: center;
}

.end-date
{
text-align: center;
}

.unavailability-reason {
 margin-left: 43%;
}

.confirm-button
{
  text-align: right;
}
```

The version of Bootstrap which I am using is 3.3.7.

Comment: css `input {border: 1px solid #ddd}`

Comment: The screenshot looks like your hand-drawn image, can you explain exactly what you are expecting to be different from the screenshot you are posting?

Comment: @Tyler Yes, the screenshot is hand-drawn image. I will explain you soon what I am expecting.

Comment: @Tyler I want to replicate a hand-drawn design with Start Date, End Date, and Please enter unavailability Reason as placeholders. I want all of those placeholders present in a rectangle box similar to the google create email  account [link](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail&hl=en) where First and Last are placeholders present in a rectangle box.

Comment: which css framework are you using?

Comment: @MarceloOrigoni I am using bootstrap.3.3.7.

Comment: as @pokeybit suggested, you need to add the border to the input, the odd thing, is bootstrap does come with that by default, something must have changed to just border-bottom

Comment: @MarceloOrigoni Is there any way I can make fiddle in angular material ? I started working on angular recently. Not sure how to do it exactly.

Comment: just add to your css file this: `input {border: 1px solid #ddd !important}`